# English words get reverted when inserted into RTL language

Tags: c#, novacode-docx

I am creating a program in c# which automatically writes and formats paragraphs in a certain way to form a document for medical use in Office Word.
For that, I am using "Novacode".
The problem is, the document is written in RTL which sometimes combines at the middle of the paragraph certain English initials.
For example, When I want to send someone to Magnetic Resonance Imaging (M.R.I) it appears as :
xxxx I.R.M xxxx xxxx 
(Remind you that it's right to left language)
Or when I want to add a signature of MD or Ph.D it appears like this:
xxxxx DM D.Ph xxx xxx

However, if I MANUALLY change the keyboard language to English and then type the English initials, they are appended just fine!

However the program is supposed to make it... And even though when I type it in the program the paragraph looks fine, when the word document is created it is ignoring my language shift to English at the middle and inverting the English initials like I explained.

Any ideas?